# Chaning Jframe images

Tags: java, image, jframe

So I'm having a hard time implementing a change in Jframe image/icon. I am using a for loop and want to change the image of the Jframe to be the corresponding image that I retrieve but I either get it stuck at the first frame or they are just piling up upon one another. I've looked online but they only show how to change the Jframe initially, not in a for loop.

This is part of my code:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();

for(int frameNum = 0; frameNum < fg.getLengthInFrames(); frameNum++) {

        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img);
        JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);
        frame.add(label);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // close canvas once the window is closed
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true); 

}
```

Comment: What is the desired results ? the current loop is packing anf setVisible=true for each iteration ... i guess you dont want to include the pack and setVisible inside the loop, but i dont fully understand what u are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

```
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int frameNum = 0; frameNum <=4; frameNum++) {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("G:/Skypecartoons/we.jpg");
                JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);
                frame.add(label);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // close canvas once the window is closed
                frame.pack();
                frame.setVisible(true); 
        }
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the icon with time you need something that will wait for some period of time allowing the user to see the icon. You need to setup the frame first and then only change the icon.

```
// setup first    
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(img);
JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);
frame.add(label);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); // close canvas once the window is closed
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

...

```
// show the frames.
for(int frameNum = 0; frameNum < fg.getLengthInFrames(); frameNum++) {
        final ImageIcon nextIcon = new ImageIcon(img);
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            label.setIcon(nextIcon);
        });
        Thread.sleep(500);
}
```